# create and use a list in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have following line of code which give me a Url value and Name in each loop. I would like to gt all these values (Url and name) and use it below in my html to render on the page. Right now one url is rendering nicely on the page, but I am not sure how to render and display the list of items .

My code:

```
 Get-ChildItem $workingDir | ForEach-Object {
    $uploadResponse = UPLOAD-FILE -workingDir $_.FullName -tempDir $tempDirectory -clientId $CLIENT_ID -clientSecret $CLIENT_SECRET -artifactname $artifactname
$url = $uploadResponse.url
$name = $uploadResponse.name
    }
```

HTML where I am putting the Url and name in the same method in the code :

```
   $OVERVIEW_PAGE_BODY_CONTENT = "<!DOCTYPE html>
    `n<html>
    `n<head>
    `n  <title>Release Notes</title>    
    `n</head>
    `n<body>
`n<p>Please click on this <a href=" + $uploadResponse.webUrl + ">$($uploadResponse.name)</a> to download the release.</p>
    
    `n</body>
    `n</html>
```

response from UPLOAD-File:

```
@{@odata.context=https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/Software/_api/v2.0/$metadata#items/$entity; @odata.type=#oneDrive.item; @odata.id=https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/Software/_api/v2.0/drives/b!oXTiJap3vEWP-R7VIhCoaK56Iw5F_2s7Jm/items/01DF22DBTHCTY; @odata.editLink=drives/b!oXTiJap3vEWP-R7VIhCoaK5C9VpM6whOqv92LwAtEd0vz2KXW2FnS6Iw5F_2s7Jm/items/01DF2VRVTLJT24SRAGJVHZSOUT2DBTHCTY; @content.downloadUrl=https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/Software/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=c9f54c6b-0644-4f4d-993a-93d0c3338a78&Translate=false&tempauth=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1oiYmY0NmQzNjAtZTAIjoiYWxsc2l0ZXMuZnVsbGNvbnRyb2wd2xBWT0&ApiVersion=2.0; createdBy=; createdDateTime=2020-12-10T17:04:06Z; eTag="{C9F54C6B-0644-4F4D-993A-93D0C3338A78},6"; id=01DHZSOUT2DBTHCTY; lastModifiedBy=; lastModifiedDateTime=2020-12-10T19:41:05Z; name=Archives.zip; parentReference=; webUrl=https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/Software/TestPipelineAutomation/Archives.zip; cTag="c:{C9F54C6B-0644-4F4D-993A-93D0C3338A78},5"; file=; fileSystemInfo=; size=7309}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [About Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) and [About Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join):

```
$Data = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Name,WebUrl
Name1,Url1
Name2,Url2
Name3,Url3
'@

$OVERVIEW_PAGE_BODY_CONTENT = @(
@'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Release Notes</title>    
</head>
<body>
'@
    # Get-ChildItem $workingDir | ForEach-Object {
    # $uploadResponse = UPLOAD-FILE -workingDir $_.FullName -tempDir $tempDirectory -clientId $CLIENT_ID -clientSecret $CLIENT_SECRET -artifactname $artifactname
    Foreach ($uploadResponse in $Data) {
        "<p>Please click on this <a href=""$($uploadResponse.webUrl)"">$($uploadResponse.name)</a> to download the release.</p>"
    }
@'
</body>
</html>
'@
) -Join [System.Environment]::NewLine
```

Comment: how do I add Name1 and URL1 in $Data??

Comment: I get that but question here is to how can i first get all the values and then show them in HTML. I get your second point but for first its still unclear and actually thats where I am struggling

Comment: UPlOAD FILE is invoking an api and returning a json aray in which I am interested in the value $uploadResponse.name and $uploadResponse.url

Comment: updated with sample response from UPLOAD-FILE:

Comment: upload file is a method which uploads my files and folders in workingDirectory to SharePoint. I am preparing a notepad here to get the links of file where it is uploaded and the file name. i hv updated question with json response

Comment: Please show the contents of the serialized json file (as shown e.g. here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/concepts/get-data), not the displayed deseralized object (I can't reconstruct the json file or object from that info)